# Migrate method RxJava1 to RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have inherited an app and I am trying to update the RxJava library.

I am having enough problems since I do not quite understand how it is programmed, I would like to know if someone can help me :)

Before publishing I searched enough on Google and here to find out how to migrate but I can't find a solution, since everything I see doesn't work.

I have an interface and a class with the methods that use Rx.

This is the interface method:

```
@GET(QUERY_ENTITIES)
Observable<Response<List<DBFile>>> dbFileList(@Path("classId") String classId, @QueryMap Map<String, String> parameters);
```

And this is the Rx method:

```
private void loadDBData(final OnDataRequestListener onDataRequestListener,
                        final OnDBCallbackListener onDBCallbackListener,
                        String classId, Map<String, String> parameters) {

    /* REQUESTS THE DBs' DATA */
    mRestInterface
            .dbFileList(classId, parameters)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .first(new Func1<Response<List<DBFile>>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Response<List<DBFile>> listResponse) {
                    if(listResponse.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;

                }
            })
            /* Separates the DB list from the response */
            .flatMap(new Func1<Response<List<DBFile>>, Observable<DBFile>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<DBFile> call(Response<List<DBFile>> responseJobs) {
                    return Observable.from(responseJobs.body());
                }

            })
            /* Transforms the data into a db data observable */
            .flatMap(new Func1<DBFile, Observable<DBFile>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<DBFile> call(DBFile data) {
                    return Observable.just(data);
                }
            })
            /* Define retry (3 Times) */
            .retry(new Func2<Integer, Throwable, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Integer attempts, Throwable throwable) {
                    return attempts <= TOTAL_RETRIES;
                }
            })
            /*
             Transforms the data into a list to receive the answer just when the entire list is loaded
             */
            .toList()
            /* Defines a request timeout */
            .timeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            /* Sends the data to the main presenter */
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<DBFile>>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    if (onDBCallbackListener instanceof VerifyApplicationUpdatesPresenter){
                        ((VerifyApplicationUpdatesPresenter) onDBCallbackListener).checkConf();
                    }else{
                        onDataRequestListener.onCompleted();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    if(e instanceof NoSuchElementException){
                        onDataRequestListener.onDataError(e.toString());
                    }else {
                        onDataRequestListener.onDataError();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<DBFile> dbFileList) {
                    if (onDBCallbackListener != null) {
                        onDBCallbackListener.onDBDataCollected(dbFileList);
                    }

                }
            });

}
```

I would greatly appreciate your help!
Thank you!

Comment: Have you read the [official guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0)? For example, `first(Func1)` has been [removed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#instance-methods) has to be converted to `filter(predicate).first()`.

Comment: Yes, I have read the official migration guide, different posts from here and other migration pages on google.
I have tried replacing Func1 with Function but also and answer, although I do not know what is "predicate" and where to get it.

I have tried many options with concatMap and other parameters and nothing works for me. My problem is that I don't know the library well and therefore, I get lost in any change.

Comment: [It's in the guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#functions): "In addition, operators requiring a predicate no longer use `Func1<T, Boolean>` but have a separate, primitive-returning type of `Predicate<T>`."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you Interface return type like below

```
 @GET(QUERY_ENTITIES)
Observable<List<DBFile>> dbFileList(@Path("classId") String classId, @QueryMap Map<String, String> parameters);
```

Change your api call function like below

```
mRestInterface.dbFileList(classId, parameters)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            /* Define retry (3 Times) */
            .retry(3)
            /* Defines a request timeout */
            .timeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            /* Sends the data to the main presenter */
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<DBFile>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<DBFile> dbFiles) {
                    if (onDBCallbackListener != null) {
                        onDBCallbackListener.onDBDataCollected(dbFileList);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    if(e instanceof NoSuchElementException){
                        onDataRequestListener.onDataError(e.toString());
                    }else {
                        onDataRequestListener.onDataError();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    if (onDBCallbackListener instanceof VerifyApplicationUpdatesPresenter){
                        ((VerifyApplicationUpdatesPresenter) onDBCallbackListener).checkConf();
                    }else{
                        onDataRequestListener.onCompleted();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: thanks you! My problem was the return of Response. Now it works correctly. Thank you very much, I was a little lost :)

Comment: @Guerry Hello! KuLdip's answer is marked as correct answer 10 hours before your comment. In addition, it is + 1 but does not appear because my reputation is low. If I have to mark it in some other way, I would appreciate it if you told me. thanks!